# Radio Buttons And Databinding in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding

I have an object with a few properties, one of which is `CarpetColor`.  I also have three radio buttons (`rbRed`, `rbBlue`, `rbGreen`) on a form within their own container.  I want to use databinding to set the object's `CarpetColor` to whichever button is checked.

I know how to do a simple binding where one control's property binds to an object property.  What I can't figure out is how to bind the result of three controls to one property.  As an example, if the user clicks 'Red', the value of `CarpetColor` should be "Red".  Similarly, if he chooses 'Green', the value of `CarpetColor` should change to "Green".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a property on a form called CarpetColor like this:

```
enum Color { Red, Blue, Green } 
public Color CarpetColor
{ 
get { return rbGreen.Checked ? Green : (rbRed.Checked ? Red : Blue); }
set 
  {  
    if (value == Green)
        rbGreen.Checked = true;
    else
        if (value == Red)
           rbRed.Checked = true;
        else
           rbBlue.Checked = true;
   }
}
```

and then you can simply bind the CarpetColor property on your form to the data source's CarpetColor.

I would make the form implements [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx)
and use radio buttons events to raise [PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged) events

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
         PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

rbGreen.CheckedChanged += (s, args) => OnPropertyChanged("CarpetColor");
rbRed.CheckedChanged += (s, args) => OnPropertyChanged("CarpetColor");
rbBlue.CheckedChanged += (s, args) => OnPropertyChanged("CarpetColor");
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of using the form's property as part of the binding process.  Thanks.

Comment: This helps me a lot. For VB.Net, the solution can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567351/form-property-databinding/16591876#16591876